# Unable to iterate through a csv.DictReader object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble iterating through a DictReader object. I'm completely stumped because the object gets returned from another function with the same properties (size and fieldnames), but I cannot figure out for the life of me how to iterate through it. I know there's been some changes on the object type, so I'll mention that this is on `Python 3.7`. Is there another way to access data in a DictReader object?

Anywho, here's relevant code. I cleaned it up to post here, so hope it's not too confusing:

```
def schedchange():
    data = otherfunction.data_get(referer_url=setup.url)
    logging.info(type(data)) # <class 'csv.DictReader'>
    import sys
    logging.info(sys.getsizeof(data)) # logs a value of 56
    logging.info(data.fieldnames) # logs the fieldnames properly
    count = 0
    for row in data:
        count += 1

    logging.info('aspen count: ')
    logging.info(count) # logs a value of: 37337
    return data

def main():
    rosters = client.schedchange()
    logger.info(rosters.fieldnames) # Prints/logs fieldname properly
    import sys
    logging.info(sys.getsizeof(rosters)) # Logs 56, the same size as in schedchange
    logging.info(type(rosters)) # <class 'csv.DictReader'>
    count = 0
    for i in rosters: #I've also tried enumerate(rosters) here
        count += 1
        logger.info(count) #nothing gets logged
    logger.info('end count: ')
    logger.info(count) # Count never gets incremented so a 0 is logged here

def data_get(self, referer_url):
    url = self.baseurl + 'quickReportMenu.do' + ';jessionid={}'.format(self.sessionid)

    r1 = get_retry(self.s, url, headers={'Referer': referer_url},
               params={'format': 'simple',
                       'extension': '0',
                       'deploymentId': 'did'})

    url = self.baseurl + 'quickReportMenu.do'
    self.payload['org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN'] = findstruts(r1.text)
    self.payload['userEvent'] = '930'
    self.payload['deploymentId'] = 'did'
    self.payload['extension'] = '0'

    p1 = post_retry(self.s, url, headers={'Referer': r1.url}, data=self.payload)

    # Extract the url for the csv from the text of the response
    popupid = findurl(p1.text)

    # Get csv
    url = self.baseurl + popupid
    d1 = get_retry_simple(self.s, url, headers={'Referer': p1.url})

    # Break text into iterable lines for each /n
    d1.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'
    iterdat = str.splitlines(d1.text)

    # Parse csv
    data = csv.DictReader(iterdat)

    return data
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "how to iterate". Why not iterate like you iterate over anything else?

Comment: Well `main` has `rosters = client.schedchange()` and `schedchange` has `data = otherfunction.data_get(referer_url=setup.url)`, but nowhere do I see where `csv.DictReader` is used? Without that this is not really answerable.

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot to include that I also checked the data type of `data`. Updated the original post

Comment: You still have not shown the code `data_get()` where `dictReader` is used. Without that there will be no answer. The only thing that be said at this point is that `data` is probably empty.

Comment: Actually, `data_get()` what supposedly *returns* a `DictReader` and you have not shown that.

Comment: Ok, I figured the log would clear that assumption of what `data_get()` returns, but I added that function to the end just now.

Comment: Really? The whole question was about `DictReader`, yet you kept hiding that information. Not sure how you figured we could guess what you did? To start on a fix I would see what the output of `iterdat` is and add a sample to the question.

Comment: Alright now I see the issue.  In `schedchange` you do for `row in data:count += 1`. That iterates over the `DictReader` object and exhausts it.  In `main` when you do `for i in rosters:` there is nothing left in the `DictReader` iterator.  Remove the iteration in `schedchange` or do something like  `data = csv.DictReader(iterdat)` over again in `main`. Or capture the values as `data_list = list(data)` and return `data_list` so it they will not be lost when passed from function to function.